# How to show this list of Info for a particular query?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, sql-execution-plan

How can i show this list of info. for a particular query?

```
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        369  recursive calls
       1689  db block gets
      48194  consistent gets
          2  physical reads
      46048  redo size
        822  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        810  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
       1500  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
      72512  rows processed
```

Comment: In which client? [SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_eight.htm#SQPUG534)?

Comment: Sql Developer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLPlus doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96533/autotrac.htm)

> SET AUTOTRACE ON STATISTICS The AUTOTRACE report shows only the SQL
>   statement execution statistics.

```
SQL> conn my_dba_user/some_password@oracle_xe_server
Connected.
SQL> set autotrace traceonly stat
SQL> select * from all_users;

21 rows selected.
```

### Statistics

```
      0  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
     20  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
   1183  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    430  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
     21  rows processed
```

SQL>